# Conditional on aggregate BIRT function

Tags: birt

I have an issue, I am working on an older version of birt (2.5) and it has a bug with standard deviation where if all of the values entered are the same, they will return NaN, I fully understand this and it took me a bit to pin down, but I know that is my issue.

what I need now is to make a conditional in the cell to make it zero if it is NaN and with my limited experience with birt, I am unsure of how to go about it.

here is the cell:

```
<cell id="1337">
                                        <property name="backgroundColor">#CFAFCF</property>
                                        <property name="textAlign">center</property>
                                        <data id="1170">
                                            <structure name="numberFormat">
                                                <property name="category">Fixed</property>
                                                <property name="pattern">#,##0.00</property>
                                            </structure>
                                            <list-property name="visibility">
                                                <structure>
                                                    <property name="format">all</property>
                                                    <expression name="valueExpr" type="javascript">var points = row["CELL_POINTS"];&#13;
var minPoints = row["CELL_MIN_POINTS"];&#13;
var maxPoints = row["CELL_MAX_POINTS"];&#13;
points == null &amp;&amp; (minPoints == null || maxPoints == null)</expression>
                                                </structure>
                                            </list-property>
                                            <property name="resultSetColumn">stddev</property>
                                        </data>
                                    </cell>
```

don't ask what the valueExpr in this is all about, I have no clue why they are doing it, but it is better to leave it alone for me :-)

I cannot post the whole thing as 1 it is huge and complex and 2, it is for work.

here is the stddev aggregation

```
<structure>
                                <property name="name">stddev</property>
                                <text-property name="displayName">stddev</text-property>
                                <property name="dataType">float</property>
                                <simple-property-list name="aggregateOn">
                                    <value>grpGeneric</value>
                                </simple-property-list>
                                <property name="aggregateFunction">STDDEV</property>
                                <list-property name="arguments">
                                    <structure>
                                        <property name="name">Expression</property>
                                        <expression name="value" type="javascript">dataSetRow["ASSIGNED_POINTS"]</expression>
                                    </structure>
                                </list-property>
                                <expression name="filterExpr" type="javascript">dataSetRow["EVAL_COUNT"] == 1</expression>
                            </structure>
```

essentially I want if the cell data is returned the value of NaN to make it 0, otherwise make it the value returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this already by adding an onRender method to the cell

1) Click on the "Layout" tab for birt
2) Click on the "outline" tab for the birt view
3) Click the cell I want the onRender method for
4) Click the "Script" tab
5) Choose "OnRender" at the top
6) add the code I want, in my case:

```
if (this.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() == "nan"){
        this.setDisplayValue(0);
} else {
       this.setDisplayValue(this.getValue());
}
```